# Why is bootstrapping binomial models producing negative estimates?

Tags: lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I'm fitting a mixed effects model to binomial data using lme4, and I'd like to bootstrap individual coefficient values. When I do so using `bootMer()`, however, I'm getting negative values even though I'm fitting a zero-intercept model. Here's the distribution of bootstrapped coefficient values (for the second coefficient). If this were doing what I'm intending, negative values should be impossible -- any ideas where I'm going wrong?

[image]

Here's sufficient code to replicate my analysis.

```
library(lme4)
dat = data.frame(era = c("recent past", "recent past", "current", "current", "current"),
                    thanksgiving.count = c(167582, 147343, 25253, 21944, 1642),
                    newyear.count = c(94908, 74728, 16063, 11970, 1039), 
                    years = c("2016-2017", "2017-2018", "2018-2019", "2019-2020", "2020-2021"))

fit = glmer(cbind(newyear.count, 
                  thanksgiving.count - newyear.count) ~ -1 + era + (1 | years), 
            data = dat, 
            family = binomial(link = "logit"))
temp = lme4::bootMer(fit, FUN = fixef, type="parametric", seed=10, nsim=10)
boots = temp$t
apply(boots, 2, range)
```

Comment: Why should negative values of parameters be impossible? The model does not have such a constraint.

Answer (score 2):

The real question is what you believe the "t" is in this case. Since you've dropped the intercept but included era as a factor, R's formula works behind the scenes and creates *this* model matrix. When you select `t` as an object from `temp`, you actually have the model coefficients from both eras aggregated together in the histogram.

```
> model.matrix(~ -1 + era , dat)
  eracurrent erarecent past
1          0              1
2          0              1
3          1              0
4          1              0
5          1              0
```

In other words, it's an ANOVA encoding and the interpretation of effects is a log odds. A negative log odds tells you that the probability of something is less than 50%. While no proportion of the actual response is less than 50%, you chose the option of "parametric" bootstrap, which simulates the response. Given that, it's not too hard to imagine that R is going to simulate a few responses where the count is less than 50% i.e. log odds is less than 0

Comment: I don't think I follow. Per boot::boot() (which bootMer()'s Value is based off of), t is "a matrix with sum(R) rows each of which is a bootstrap replicate of the result of calling statistic." This squares with the fact that colMeans(boots) and fixef(fit) are approximately the same. If the results were being presented on log odds scale, given that the coefficient estimates of the model fit are both less than 1 (0.42 and 0.14), I would expect the majority of the values produced to be negative.

Update: I'm an idiot. fixef(fit) is also giving estimates on the link scale. Thanks!